# Table view cells overlapping when deleting

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have text in a table view cell which displays in one line. When the 'edit' button is pressed and the negative sign is pressed to display the delete button. This pushes the text in the cell into two lines causing the cells to overlap. My cells also have subtitles. I have text in other cells that take two lines and when deleting get truncated. I set `cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2` to do this so that's not a issue.

How can I get the one line text to only display in one line when the delete button appears? keeping the two line text in the cells as is.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution...it isn't as complicated as I thought

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Favorites *favorite = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = favorite.name;
    NSLog(@"%d",[favorite.name length]);
    NSLog(@"%@",favorite.name);
    if ([favorite.name length] <= 34) {
       cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
       NSLog(@"no. of lines = 1");
    }else{
       cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
       NSLog(@"no. of lines = 2");
}
cell.detailTextLabel.text = favorite.subTopic;}
```

The `configureCell` method is called in my `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Basically I'm checking for the number of characters in the string. I found the magic number to be 34 characters so that everything fits.